# How do I get email sent to address I do not own?

Tags: email, address

My email address is something like: justme@gmail.com.
I keep on getting lots of junk mail addressed to (for example): justmex2@aol.com. I don’t have an aol.com account. They alter what follows “justme” to any other characters and add aol.com. How does that address on an email get through to me?  How can that be blocked?

Comment: I suppose it is possible that the spammer is spoofing the email address. You can view the raw source of the email and the header will likely show that. I get emails like that from time to time, that **say** they are from me at my gmail address or some others. I just mark them as spam and rely on Google's spam algorithm to sort out where it *really* came from.

Comment: @SteveChambers - you have a whole larger issue if people can pretend to send from you. Investigate DKIM & DMARC security on your domain.

Comment: Ah… I suppose if 'your domain' is gmail, you're screwed… sorry. If google can't keep their authentication safe… meh...

Comment: “How can that be blocked?” - You can’t

Answer (score 0):

You get those mails probably because your address is in bcc.

Avoiding those mails requires the same actions you take to avoid spam you receive normally to your address.

Comment: …one of which is make sure your spam filter also prevents any read receipt or remote data access, for example downloading any image content, so the mailer gets zero indication that the mail ever arrived at all.